# Docker file with input/output files from multiple locations

Tags: python-3.x, docker, input, output, docker-volume

I have a python program, that takes lots of different inputs (but lets just say -i for input file and -db for database and -o for output file, that the program creates.)
So I would run the program like this:
`python3 myprogram.py -i /path/to/inputfile -db /another/path/to/database -o /a/different/path/to/outputfile`
This program runs with no problems through the command line.

Now I am trying to make a dockerfile, that runs this program. I would like to be able to use inputfiles and database files outside the docker (so I can use multiple different files every time I run the container). And I also want to be able to access the output file outside the container.

I know I can use volumes, but I have only seen examples with 1 path to 1 inputfile. What if there are multiple inputfiles and outputfiles, that I want to access outside the container?

My Dockerfile ends with:

`ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "/usr/src/myprogram.py"]`

So, how can I achieve this? I have been searching and searching, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the primary goal of your program is to read and write host files, an isolation system like Docker that's specifically designed to prevent containers from accessing the host filesystem probably isn't what you want; a Python virtual environment might work better.  Why do you want to introduce Docker here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use as many volumes as you like but you need to specify them during container launch, not in Dockefile. That is

```sh
docker run -v /host/path:/container/path some_image:latest command
```

You can mount several directories with multiple `-v` keys.